# The method get($sku) of ProductRepository returns null in UnitTest

Tags: magento2, phpunit

I've developed a module that must return some data by REST. When I call it by web browser everything works as well, but when I
 call it by test class, PHPUnit Test, the method get($sku) of interface Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface returns a null value.
What am I doing wrong?
 My method setUp()

```
protected function setUp()
{
    $this->objectManager = new \Magento\Framework\TestFramework\Unit\Helper\ObjectManager($this);
    $this->priceService = $this->objectManager->getObject('my_class');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In unit tests there is no database. That means to test interaction with a repository you should replace the repository with a test double that returns a predefined value for "get()"

Since you did not show the actual test code and I don't know what you are trying to test, I cannot go into much detail. But the keyword you are looking for is "mock objects"